# git: add line at the end of an existing commit without using editor

Tags: git

Is it possible to auto amend an existing commit with a bug ID retrieved from a script, without launching the editor ?

Something like `git commit --amend -C HEAD -s` where instead of `-s` which adds the `Signed-off-by:` I want to add a `Bug: xxxxx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git commit --amend -m "$(git log -1 --pretty=%B)" -m "Bug: xxxx"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add the "Bug" line to the end, you could use something like this:

```
(git show --pretty=format:%B -s HEAD; echo; echo "Bug: 12345") | \
    git commit --amend -F-
```

Answer (score 2):

Use command like this:

```
git -c core.editor='git interpret-trailers --in-place --trailer=Foo:bar' commit --amend
```